# Trying to use COUNT as SQL query via fetch_object() but it doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, count, fetch

So this is what my screen gives me

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
1
stdClass Object
(
    [COUNT('user_id')] => 0
)
1
```

I'm trying to access the [COUNT('user_id')] part, but I can't seem to find out how on the internet. The code I'm using is:

```
    $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM user_credentials WHERE email='$email'");

echo "<pre>", print_r($query), "</pre>";

if($query->num_rows){
    while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
        echo "<pre>", print_r($row), "</pre><br />";
        #echo "<h1>", $row->COUNT['user_id'], "</h1>"; 
    }
}
```

Obviously the trouble is $row->COUNT['user_id'], but I don't know how to access that. It's not an array so I'm at a loss. I've just begun learning objects.

Comment: SELECT COUNT('user_id') as c,  use alias in your query... and fetch with alias name... or use {}...

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! But I have a follow-up question. Does that mean I will always have to use aliases when doing COUNT queries?

Comment: its good practice using aliases for max, count, min etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias in your query as follows

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT('user_id')  as c FROM user_credentials WHERE email='$email'");
```

and fetch alias name... it will solve your problem...